# Pulling multiple entries based on ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

I got the row_num column from a partition. I want each Type to match with at least one Sent and one Resent. For example, Jon's row is removed below because there is no Resent. Kim's Sheet row is also removed because again, there is no Resent. I tried using a CTE to take all columns for a Code if row_num = 2 but Kim's Sheet row obviously shows up because they're all under one Code. If anyone could help, that'd be great!

Edit: I'm using SSMS 2018. There are multiple Statuses other than Sent and Resent.

What my table looks like:

```
+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| Code  | Name   | Type   | Status  | row_num | 
+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
|   123 | Jon    |  Sheet |    Sent |     1   |           
|   221 | Kim    |  Sheet |    Sent |     1   |          
|   221 | Kim    |   Book |  Resent |     1   |            
|   221 | Kim    |   Book |    Sent |     2   |            
|   221 | Kim    |   Book |    Sent |     3   |  
+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
```

What I want it to look like:

```
+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| Code  | Name   | Type   | Status  | row_num | 
+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+     
|   221 | Kim    |   Book |   Resent|     1   |            
|   221 | Kim    |   Book |    Sent |     2   |            
|   221 | Kim    |   Book |    Sent |     3   |  
+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Here is my CTE code:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM #MyTable
)
SELECT * 
FROM #MyTable
WHERE Code IN (SELECT Code FROM CTE WHERE row_num = 2)
```

Comment: Why do you not post what you "I tried using a CTE"  ?

Comment: Please specify which sql dialect is it.

Comment: Does your `status` column have only two possible values?

Answer (score 2):

If `sent` and `resent` are the only values for `status`, then you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.type = t.type and
                    t2.status <> t.status
             );
```

You can also phrase this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(status) over (partition by name, type) as min_status,
             max(status) over (partition by name, type) as max_status
      from t
     ) t
where min_status <> max_status;
```

Both of these can be tweaked if other `status` values are possible.  However, based on your question and sample data, that does not seem necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b6b421fdd21134bbbd3d2bf0ad8f34a6)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(ID integer,Name VARCHAR(10),Type VARCHAR(10),Status VARCHAR(10),row_num integer);

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES
('123','Jon','Sheet','Sent','1'),
('221','Kim','Sheet','Sent','1'),
('221','Kim','Book','Resent','1'),
('221','Kim','Book','Sent','2'),
('221','Kim','Book','Sent','3');

SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  select 1
  from Table1 t2
  where t2.Name=t1.Name 
    and t2.Type=t1.TYpe 
    and t2.Status = case when t1.Status='Sent'
        then 'Resent' 
        else 'Sent' end)
```

Comment: This works great if the only 2 values for `Status` are `Sent` and `Resent`.  If you change the `else 'Sent' end` to `when t1.Status = 'Resent' then 'Sent' end` it will work with other values as well.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you would provide some scripts to create table and put these test data, but try something like

```
with a1 as (
    select 
      name, type, 
      row_number() over (partition by code, Name, type, status) as rn 
    from #MyTable
), a2 as (
    select * from a1 where rn > 1
)
select t.* 
from #MyTable as t 
inner join a2 on t.name = a2.name and t.type = a2.type;
```

Here you

1. calculate another row number using partitions by code, name, type and status,
2. then fetch these with this new row number > 1
3. and finally, you use that to join to original table and get interesting you rows

Syntax may vary on MSSQL, but you should give it a try. And please use better names than me ;-)

This solution is quite generic because it doesn't rely on used statuses. They're not hardcoded. And you can easily control what matters by changing partitions.

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8yoxN8vge6nJJdp6MjkhMr/0)